# How do I tell my reputation ranking?

Tags: support

When on the 'Top Users' tab of the Stack Exchange website, you can see the reputation rankings (that is, 1st place has the most reputation, 2nd place has the 2nd most, etc.) of different users. Recently, I searched for my name, and nothing came up. (Probably because I'm rather new.) However, when I searched under the 'Users' tab on PPCG, I saw my name, but no ranking. So, how do I find my reputation ranking, or does it only count if I am a 'Top User'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom of the users page has a link to the [weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/88/week/codegolf):

[image]

This shows your own spot at the top of list. However, this list only includes users with at least 200 reputation, so you'll need to get a bit more rep before you show up.

Also, when you get there, I think this list is only updated once a day.